# creating a facebook app showing events in joomla

Tags: facebook, joomla

i'm searching the internet for a good howto concerning facebook developing, but can't find it. I created a facebook developer account, i also created an app (which is in developing mode).
But now i'm stuck...

I want to show the events of (my) facebook (fan) page in my Joomla website. I can find (joomla) modules for the website part, but they all say that i need a facebook app. Unfortunately nobody is explaining how you do this...

My question: what do i need to do in the facebook developer portal to create this functionality?
(if there is a representative example somewhere please refer me to it).

Thanks for the time and effort!

Kind regard,
Mijno

Answer (score 0):

When you integrate your blog or cms with an app that you admin, you don't need special permissions.
So just create a facebook developer account.
Go to Apps & create an new app.
Fill in the fields. This will create a standard app and provides you with an App ID and the App Secret. This should be enough.